# How to select all imgs which id starts with "menu" or "submenu"?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to do such thing in css or in a jquery selector?

```
img[id^='menu' || id^='submenu'] { //...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `img[id^='menu'],img[id^='submenu']`

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, and it pays you that time back *very* quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("img[id^='menu'], img[id^='submenu']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$("img[id^='submenu'],img[id^='menu']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through [Multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and  [StringStart with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("img[id^='menu'], img[id^='submenu']")
```